# Converting layer file ArcGIS desktop 10.2 to 10.0 fails

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, layer-file

I am having problems with converting an ArcGIS 10.2 layer file to a 10.0 layer file.
I used ArcGIS online to import webmaptiles into my ArcMap 10.2.2. desktop version. In order to use them offline, I saved them as a layer file.

My colleague uses ArcMap 10.0, so I saved the layer file as a 10.0 version.
However, when adding this layer in ArcMap 10.0 he gets following error message:

*Adding the selected layer file failed.
Possible reasons include that it may have been created using a newer version of ArcGIS and can't be opened in the version you are using.*

What causes this conversion to fail?

I tried importing the webmaptiles using ArcGIS online on his computer, but this did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

The layer file is a reference to the ArcGis Online webmaptiles.
So the original source is still in v10.2 and saving the layer to a format supported by 10.0 isn't changing that.

So you need to retrieve the original file and save it to 10.0